# Support in-app purchases on both old and new androids

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-play-services

I'm developing an app with so called in-app purchases.
I've implemented already using in-app billing v3 which requires last version of google play services.

The problem is that on my pretty old phone (android 2.3.6) I was unable to update google play so in-app purchases didn't work

On developer.android.com it is written that v2 of billing library differs a lot from v3 and is currently deprecated.

What would you suggest to me to support old phones without last version of google play?

1) rewriting using v2 - seems inappropriate. And does it mean that every time I would like to support old phones I should sucrifice the power experience top android models could offer?

2) making 2 versions of an app - one for new and second for old phones - seems a better solution. But I thought that it's impossible to publish 2 apps with same name and package. And what is also important - in this case users which have new devices will see both versions in google play (because their device supports both of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play IAPs do no use Google-Play-Services but Google Play:

> In-app Billing Version 3 is supported on devices running Android 2.2
>   or higher that have the latest version of the Google Play store
>   installed.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html#api)

It should work properly on your device.

Comment: My mistake. It means that I cannot update googleplay which looks like an old version

Answer (score 0):

You can check Google play store version 3.9.16 or higher in your application and more then 85% users using greater version according to my knowledge. And @Hartok is also right if you are using 2.3 then you just need to update Google play store app, generally play store application will be updated automatically for most of devices.

Please check this link it may be useful for your given issue:

> http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/versions.html

And also check this link:

> https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153481?hl=en

you can check Google play store version at run time and ask user to update Google play store version. Code to check play store version can be found in the given link above.